# username duplication validation

Tags: c#, sql

I'm making a simple log-in page for out thesis and I'm already done with the character length and password mismatch validation.. my problem is how do I test **if the given username already exist in my database**.... I'm coding in C# and making use of SQL management studio R2 for my database....

```
private void add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string UserName = textBox1.Text;
  string Password = maskedTextBox1.Text;

  if (Password.Length <= MiN_LENGHT && UserName.Length <= MiN_LENGHT)
  {
    errorProvider1.SetError(textBox1, "User name must be at least 8 character");
    errorProvider2.SetError(maskedTextBox1, @"Password must be at least 8 character");

    maskedTextBox1.Clear();
    maskedTextBox2.Clear();
  }
  else if (maskedTextBox1.Text != maskedTextBox2.Text)
  {
    errorProvider1.SetError(maskedTextBox2, "Passwords don't match");

    maskedTextBox1.Clear();
    maskedTextBox2.Clear();
  }
  else if (textBox1.Text == "" || maskedTextBox1.Text == "" || 
           maskedTextBox2.Text == "")
  {
    MessageBox.Show("Please fill up the required records", "Information", 
                     MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
  }
  else
  {
    x.da.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand(@"Insert into PlayerList 
                                         VALUES(@uname,@pw,@repw)", x.cs);
    x.da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@uname", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value =
                                         textBox1.Text;
    x.da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@pw", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value =  
                                         maskedTextBox1.Text;
    x.da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@repw", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = 
                                         maskedTextBox2.Text;
    x.cs.Open();
    x.da.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("Record Added", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
                                         MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    button3.Enabled = true;
    x.da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand( @"Select PlayerCode, uname from 
                                         PlayerList", x.cs);
    x.ds.Clear();
    x.da.Fill(x.ds);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = x.ds.Tables[0];
    x.cs.Close();
  }
}
```

hope you can help....

Comment: Do you really need to write this yourself? Because the membership Provider has all this built-in.

Comment: As an aside, you seem to be storing the passwords as plain text, this is not a good idea.

Comment: if you don't have any resctriction on user table the SqlMembershipProvider & FormsAuthentication is the best solution in my opinion. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649314.aspx

Comment: Is there a uniqueness constraint on the `uname` column?

Answer (score 2):

You can add a UNIQUE CONSTRAINT or INDEX on the username field in the database and catch the exception, or you can search for it beforehand. I recommend the first alternative, as it avoids a race condition, but that shouldn't preclude you from doing the search as well.

Comment: I would not recommend the first alternative as you shouldn't depend on exceptions to check if something worked.

Comment: @SimonHalsey So, save for creating a stored procedure with transaction handling, which seems rather out of scope for this question, how do you avoid the race condition? The database has to ensure integrity of the data.

Comment: You accept a race condition may occur sometimes, but it'll be the exception. Use the UNIQUE constraint as you've suggested, but just do the check first & handle duplicates. You'll avoid throwing most of the exceptions which are expensive. If a race occurs catch & handle it.

Comment: @SimonHalsey That's what "Preclude" means

Comment: That bit wasn't clear. I read it as you suggesting using exceptions for flow control.

Answer (score 1):

Before you store the new user, you first do a check if that username already exists in the database, if the user does not exist then you save that record.

if that username does exist you skip saving it, and show a friendly message to the user that his or her username is already in use

Comment: But you still need a constraint and handle the error, because of concurrency.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to do the validation in log-in page? I think this validation done is sign-up page.

You can do this validation in two ways

1--> Do an ajax call after user enters username and show the duplicate message if username already exists.(Mean while user will be providing password so user time will be saved).

2--> In the 2nd approach you can do the validation completely in server side. Get the username and compare it with existing user names and show the message accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

on textchanged event of username textbox you just query from databse that

```
 select username from user_mst where username='"+textusernm.text+"';
```

if it is there then jst display error message and disable save button 
& if not jst enable save button and save it

Comment: This is a horrible way to do it. It's completely open to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: this just way i am showing even i know that we can use parameters for passing textbox value and even we can encrypt it and then pass it..i thought i dn need to explain it to you thats why jst written like this and there are many ways of passing values it's depends on ypu how you are passing to prevent sql injection

Comment: You don't have to explain it to me, no. To the OP, yes. It's never good to give a bad example when showing a principle. =)

Comment: I know that but HOW would it check if it does exist?

Comment: for that i gave you that 'select' for existing user and when you type user name in textbox query will pic that value and check that user name in databse on  textchanged event, if it will find that name in db then it will enable your save button then you can save it else not